# How to get dates and hours from a ReactJS Form?

Tags: reactjs, date

I need to get some user information from a Form built using ReactJS and React Bootstrap.

The user information I need to get from the Form are the days and the hours he worked.

---

E.g.:

```
21/01/2022 - from 09:00 to 16:00 and from 19:00 to 21:00

24/01/2022 - from 11:00 to 16:00

27/01/2022 - from 09:00 to 13:00 and from 17:00 to 20:00

...and so on
```

---

How can I built a ReactJS Form (maybe using React Bootstrap) to get this user info?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a specific library or component that allows for date/time selection, or potentially one for selecting dates and one for selecting time ranges (as that's a complex problem). Don't try to roll it yourself from scratch, it's not worth the level of effort-- there's a lot of complexity with time selection.

Stack Overflow isn't meant for suggesting specific libraries/frameworks, so just do a search for [react date time picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+date+time+picker) or [javascript date time picker](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+time+picker). It's possible that some non-React libraries would be better suited for what you need, and you can create a react wrapper for them. Good luck!